# Legend on an empty plot gives no colors

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a legend on an empty plot in R, but when I specify the colors argument on the legend function I don't get any colors.

```
plot(1, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
legend(1, 1, legend = c("h","w"), col=c("red","green"))
```

I only see the labels of legend but not the colors.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the colours irrespective of a shape you can also use the `fill` argument instead.

```
plot(1, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
legend(1, 1, legend = c("h","w"), fill=c("red","green"))
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: actually it puts a shape : a box one ;-)

Comment: @CathG Haha it truly does :)

Answer (score 4):

you have to choose something to put into colors. Here, you're telling R the colors but no object. You can choose, for example:

a plain line : `legend(1, 1, legend = c("h","w"), col=c("red","green"), lty=1)`  [image]
a point : `legend(1, 1, legend = c("h","w"), col=c("red","green"), pch=19)`

[image]

Or another type of line or symbol but you need to specify in the legend call what you want to put in colors.

*To complete @LyzandeR 's suggestion, if you want the border of the boxes to be of same colors as the filling, you need to also use `border`:*

```
plot(1, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
legend(1, 1, legend = c("h","w"), fill=c("red","green"), border=c("red","green"))
```

[image]